# parsing JSON file in flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter

I am parsing this type of JSON file in flutter but I am getting error.
initially, I am able to print the whole data in the console but when I want only the name it gives me an error.
bellow in the image for JSON file.
[image]

this the code that I wrote for parsing which gives me 1st value of name as "Abul-Abbas" then it throws an error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_appnew/Constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_appnew/network.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';




const URL ='https://xxxx-api.someapp.com/xxx';

class TabData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabDataState createState() => _TabDataState();
}



class _TabDataState extends State<TabData> {

  List image = [];
  List Name = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.fetchUser();
  }




  fetchUser() async{
    var response = await http.get(URL);
    print(response.statusCode);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var items = json.decode(response.body)[0]['name'];
      print(items);
      setState(() {
        Name = items;
      });
    }
    else{
      setState(() {
        Name = [];
      });
    }
  }








  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: Name.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
      return getCard(context, index);
    },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(thickness: 2,),
    );
  }



  Widget getCard(BuildContext context, int index){
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: [
              
              Container(
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage('${image[index]}'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(width: 20,),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[

                  Text('${Name[index]}', style: kListTileTextNameStyle,),

                ],
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the same is happening with the image I am not able to show it.
please help this is my first time with JSON file parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can advice you to try to avoid the dynamic type. Your

```
var items = json.decode(response.body)[0]['name'];
```

assigns the items to be the type String and the value is "Abul-Abbas". After that you assign `Name` which is a List to `items` which is of type String.
What you actually want to do is to add all names to the list (I guess).

So you should do:

```
response.body.forEach((element) {
  Name.add(element["name"]);
});
```

I also recommend Renaming `Name` to `names`.
If you just wanted the first value of your response, then Name should be of type String.